# Can I access the wordpress REST api on a wordpress.com free site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

In many wordpress sites you can access their JSON api by appending a `wp-json` suffix to the URL; for instance, 'https://spectator.co.uk/wp-json'

...however this doesn't appear to work on wordpress.com hosted sites that I've seen, such as https://nookhdplusandroid7.wordpress.com.

Is the API only for standalone and / or premium sites, would anyone know?

Comment: But use this tho https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/nookhdplusandroid7.wordpress.com/

Comment: @CameronHurd looks like we have a winner, thanks!